# ASP.Net Core Vendor Specific Mime Type in HTTP POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In order to make the model binder correctly bind the body part of an HTTP request in ASP.Net Core you need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
public JsonResult PostContent([FromBody] Content content)
{
    ......
}
```

This works great if your media type is `application/json`. However, if you want to use a vendor specific (e.g. `application/vnd+mycompany+json`) media type in your `Accept` header then if I pass that in the HTTP POST I will get a `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

So my question is *how do you support vendor specific media types in ASP.Net Core?*

Comment: Check custom formatters as mentioned in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it.

In `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IApiInfoService, ApiInfoService>();
    services.AddTransient<IApiVersion, ApiVersion>();
    services.AddTransient<IContentService, ContentService>();
    services.AddTransient<IIdGenerator, GuidIdGenerator>();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(
        mvcConfig => {
            mvcConfig.InputFormatters.OfType<JsonInputFormatter>().First().SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentTypes.VENDOR_MIME_TYPE)
            );
        }
    );
}
```